# Two-column list with opposite alignments from single UL?

Tags: css, layout, alignment

How does one make a two-column stacked list, one left-aligned, one right-aligned out of one `<UL>` element? So far, I can only get elements to float next to each other when I need them to stack like block level elements.

**Desired layout (from PSD):**

[image: Desired layout]

**What I have so far:**
[image: Current Layout]
**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="top_nav">
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hitched</a></li>
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hatched</a></li>
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Details</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Readymade</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS (SCSS):**

```
header {
    padding-top: $row / 4;
    padding-left: $cols*2 - $gut;
    padding-right: $cols*2 - $gut;
    padding-bottom: $row / 3;
    .top_nav {
        .group_a {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
        }
        .group_b {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: The floated elements show up next to each other, where they should be stacked as shown in the Desired layout image.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. Can you make a fiddle for us to play with?

Comment: Do you have to stick with this HTML? Because 3dgoo has a good solution if you can change the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can set `float: left;` only for `.group_a` and `text-align: right;` for `.group_b`:

**CSS**

```
.group_a {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
.group_b {
  text-align: right;
}
```

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bfFjp)

This way you don't have to change your `li` order. Keep in mind, that you might experience some problems in lte IE7.

Answer (score 2):

If you can rearrange the html elements so `group_a` and `group_b` alternate, then you can use `clear` to achieve this:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="top_nav">
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hitched</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hatched</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Details</a></li>
        <li class="group_a"><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
        <li class="group_b"><a href="#">Readymade</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```css
nav {
    padding-top: $row / 4;
    padding-left: $cols*2 - $gut;
    padding-right: $cols*2 - $gut;
    padding-bottom: $row / 3;
    .top_nav {
        .group_a {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
        }
        .group_b {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9jjR/)**

Comment: A fair solution, assuming I can figure out how to stagger them in javascript.